# Mobile Touch_Tap event VS MouseEvent Click

Tags: actionscript-3

guys I am new to action script3.0 when it comes to mobile app development, would like to ask. Is a mouse click event that I used to change from one scene to another example below, would it be the same as a tap event observed in the app or do I need to add a mobile touch, tap event function to do the same?

Really need pros advise on this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Lots of thanks in advance to all.

```
eCharge.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);   function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop("eCharge");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the AIR runtime dispatches a mouse event in addition to a touch event, that's regulated by [`Multitouch.mapTouchToMouse`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#mapTouchToMouse) flag. So that your `click` listener will be executed.

Though, to improve performance that's recommended to set the flag to `false` and listen for `TouchEvent` instead. For instance you can add both listeners at the same time, one will for for desktops and another for mobile (but don't forget to set `Multitouch.mapTouchToMouse = false` otherwise you will get listener executed twice on desktop).

```
eCharge.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);
eCharge.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TAP, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and advise. Multitouch.mapTouchToMouse = false, should it be included in the function or declare together with the instances?

Comment: That's a static settings which should be done once at app start at some point

Comment: Noted, Thanks for your advise

Comment: welcome, feel free to accept the answer if it solves your issue